# Typeable dropdown in sapui5 , adding values to dropdown by typing

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, sapui5, dropdownbox

I have a simple dropdown in SAPUI5 view. It's populated and works fine. My only concern, if there is a list of team in the dropdown like:

> Team 1
>   Team 2
>   Team 3
>   Team 4

etc., but there is no Team 9 let's say, in the dropdown, can I make it so that I can type in the new value? (Then I would save it to the database and refresh the JSON model for it, so it would have the new value).

Comment: You could use a `ComboBox` instead of a `Dropdown` or `Select`, and do the storing of the new entry yourself

Comment: oh... it was that simple... thank you :)